# CronScheduleBuilder in Quartz Scheduler in java

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz Scheduler and i need to make a scheduler which will execute specific job at every three months into the program. so how do i make that cronExpression so i can do this things in java?
I need one month,Two month six month interval.

Comment: what is the current time expression you are using ?

Comment: (0/5 * * * * ?) this is what i am using but can u explain it? how it works. ?

Comment: thats for trigerring every 5 seconds
try this 
"0 0 0 * 1,4,7,10 ? "

Comment: Unexpected end of expression. error using that.

Comment: i made an edit, try that

Comment: Check it out dude again u wrong its not for every 5 sec check again. bcoz sec is first in queue. u put there "0" check/

Comment: Well this will help and it helps me :) http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression is tested and works perfectly for quartz 2.2

```
"0 0 0 1 1/3 ?"
```

The above expression will fire every 3 months starting Jan 1st at 00:00 hours. Next will be on April 1st at 00:00 hrs.

for every 2 months use this

```
    "0 0 0 1 1/2 ?"
```

You can change the first three zeros as you like. They refer to the time on the 1st of the month. The next number ,ie, "1" in my case is the date.

Comment: is it working? and ya how do i try this code and ya i have to change my cal date for that is it?

Comment: Can u tell me one thing what this ? means??

Comment: yes you have to manipulate your system calender to test the code.
To test it use this 


        String time = "0 0 0 1 1/3 ?";
        JobKey jobKey2 = new JobKey("job1", "group1");
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class).withIdentity(jobKey2).build();
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("dsd", "group1").
                withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(time)).build();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

Comment: and this might be for every 6 month. "0 0 0 1 1/6 ?" is it?